# How can I mimic the loss of focus styling with CSS in Java FX?

Tags: css, javafx-8

In my application I have a specific styling that states that yellow should be used to represent required fields.  In my grids, I have implemented this as follows:

```
.table-cell-required-field {
    -fx-control-inner-background: -sif-required_field-color;
    -fx-background-color:-fx-table-cell-border-color, -fx-control-inner-background;
    -fx-border-color: deepskyblue  deepskyblue  deepskyblue  deepskyblue ;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-padding: 0.0em;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-inner-color;
}


.table-cell-required-field:selected {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-focus-color, -fx-cell-focus-inner-border, -fx-focus-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
}
```

This works just fine - however, when the table isn't focused, the selected field is staying -fx-focus-color rather than reverting back to the standard in modena which has it as gray - which is confusing the users.

I have tried to use focus as a psuedo class as well - but looking in ScenicView both cells show both selected and focused and this has no change.

Here is an example of what I need to happen when the table isn't focused:
[image]

However when I select the required field and then selected the other table it stays blue - I need this to go gray when it doesn't have focus.
[image]

I would appreciate any help in what I am missing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```css
.table-cell-required-field {
    -fx-control-inner-background: -sif-required_field-color;
    -fx-background-color:-fx-table-cell-border-color, -fx-control-inner-background;
    -fx-border-color: deepskyblue  deepskyblue  deepskyblue  deepskyblue ;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-padding: 0.0em;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-inner-color;
}

.table-view .table-cell-required-field:selected {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-focus-color, -fx-cell-focus-inner-border, -fx-selection-bar-non-focused;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
}

.table-view:focused .table-cell-required-field:selected {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-focus-color, -fx-cell-focus-inner-border, -fx-focus-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
}
```

Typically for styling at this level I look at the default `modena.css` stylesheet, which you can extract from your jfxrt.jar file, or see at the [OpenJFX source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u60/rt/file/996511a322b7/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css).

Comment: Thank you - the top portion worked - the bottom portion kept the same behavior as before.  I scoured modena.css - but couldn't see what was wrong.